# using lodash transform same keys into one and create array of it's values

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I would like to transform belo `input.json` file. I would like to merge all the category key into one and create array of names, if it matches.

I am looking for a solution using only lodash or only JS/ES*

There are similar questions already asked, but most of them involve two different json's. Please shed some light on the solution

```
[
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Bhaijan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Sallu"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Dabangg Khan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Sultan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Shahrukh Khan",
        "names": "SRK"
    },
    {
        "category": "Shahrukh Khan",
        "names": "King Khan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Akshay Kumar",
        "names": "Khiladi"
    },
    {
        "category": "Akshay Kumar",
        "names": "Akki"
    },
    {
        "category": "Aamir Khan",
        "names": "A.K."
    },
    {
        "category": "Aamir Khan",
        "names": "Mr. Perfectionist"
    },
    {
        "category": "Priyanka Chopra",
        "names": "Piggy Chops"
    },
    {
        "category": "Kareena Kapoor",
        "names": "Bebo"
    }
]
```

`expected json`

```
[
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": ["Bhaijan", "Sallu", "Dabangg Khan", "Sultan"]
    },
    {
        "category": "Shahrukh Khan",
        "names": ["SRK", "King Khan"]
    },
    {
        "category": "Akshay Kumar",
        "names": ["Khiladi", "Akki", "A.K."]
    },
    {
        "category": "Aamir Khan",
        "names": ["Mr. Perfectionist"]
    },
    {
        "category": "Priyanka Chopra",
        "names": ["Piggy Chops"]
    },
    {
        "category": "Kareena Kapoor",
        "names": ["Bebo"]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the array using [**Array#reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function and check if an object already exist with the current item name. If yes, just push the name into it, if not create a new object with the current item name.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Bhaijan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Sallu"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Dabangg Khan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Sultan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Shahrukh Khan",
        "names": "SRK"
    },
    {
        "category": "Shahrukh Khan",
        "names": "King Khan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Akshay Kumar",
        "names": "Khiladi"
    },
    {
        "category": "Akshay Kumar",
        "names": "Akki"
    },
    {
        "category": "Aamir Khan",
        "names": "A.K."
    },
    {
        "category": "Aamir Khan",
        "names": "Mr. Perfectionist"
    },
    {
        "category": "Priyanka Chopra",
        "names": "Piggy Chops"
    },
    {
        "category": "Kareena Kapoor",
        "names": "Bebo"
    }
]

const arr = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  
  const found = acc.find(i => i.category === item.category);
  
  if(found) {
     found.names.push(item.names);
  } else {
     acc.push({category: item.category, names: [item.names]})
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, However can you explain what does the last empty parameter do `}, []);`

Comment: It is the signature of the `reduce` function. I just pass an empty array as a start value for the `acc` inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lodash#groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy), to group each object in the collection by the `category` key, and then [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#map) to transform each group into an array format of your liking.

```
var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('category')
  .map(function(group, category) {
    return {
      category: category,
      names: _.map(group, 'names')
    };
  })
  .value();
```

```js
var data = [
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Bhaijan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Sallu"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Dabangg Khan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Sultan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Shahrukh Khan",
        "names": "SRK"
    },
    {
        "category": "Shahrukh Khan",
        "names": "King Khan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Akshay Kumar",
        "names": "Khiladi"
    },
    {
        "category": "Akshay Kumar",
        "names": "Akki"
    },
    {
        "category": "Aamir Khan",
        "names": "A.K."
    },
    {
        "category": "Aamir Khan",
        "names": "Mr. Perfectionist"
    },
    {
        "category": "Priyanka Chopra",
        "names": "Piggy Chops"
    },
    {
        "category": "Kareena Kapoor",
        "names": "Bebo"
    }
];

var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('category')
  .map(function(group, category) {
    return {
      category: category,
      names: _.map(group, 'names')
    };
  })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the possible solution using reduce method.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Bhaijan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Sallu"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Dabangg Khan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Salman Khan",
        "names": "Sultan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Shahrukh Khan",
        "names": "SRK"
    },
    {
        "category": "Shahrukh Khan",
        "names": "King Khan"
    },
    {
        "category": "Akshay Kumar",
        "names": "Khiladi"
    },
    {
        "category": "Akshay Kumar",
        "names": "Akki"
    },
    {
        "category": "Aamir Khan",
        "names": "A.K."
    },
    {
        "category": "Aamir Khan",
        "names": "Mr. Perfectionist"
    },
    {
        "category": "Priyanka Chopra",
        "names": "Piggy Chops"
    },
    {
        "category": "Kareena Kapoor",
        "names": "Bebo"
    }
];

const resultObject = data.reduce((acc, value) => {
  acc[value.category] = acc[value.category] || [];
  acc[value.category].push(value.names);
  return acc; 
},{});

const results = Object.keys(resultObject).map(key => ({ category: key, names: resultObject[key]}));

console.log(results);
```